# Displaying results of added textbox value in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am updating this issue with the hope of getting some help because I am pickled by this problem.

This code allows a user co fill the current row made up of three textboxes.

Then if needed, user clicks the Add More Rows button to add more rows and fills the rows up.

This works ok.

My issue is how to display the results of these rows.

For instance, the rows are laid out as such:

```
Name: John Doe      Address: 123 Address way      Email: Johndoe@yahoo.com
Name: Jane Doe      Address: 1 Druid Hills Rd     Email: Janedoe@otmail.com
```

When the user clicks Continue, I would like to display these results on a separate page.

So far, only the last record, sometimes the first record gets displayed but not all the rows entered.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

First, here is my gridview and then my attempt to display the results.

```
  <asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDeleting="Gridview1_RowDeleting">
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" Visible="false" HeaderText="Row Number" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server" style="width:200px;"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Adress">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" style="width:200px;"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
        <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" style="width:200px;"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <FooterTemplate>
         <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add More Rows" 
                onclick="ButtonAdd_Click" />
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

My attempt at displaying the rows which is failing miserably.

```
Private Sub FillSummary()
    SetRowData()


    Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0

    Dim sc As New StringCollection()

    If ViewState("CurrentTable") IsNot Nothing Then


        Dim dtCurrentTable As DataTable = DirectCast(ViewState("CurrentTable"), DataTable)

        If dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then

            For i As Integer = 1 To dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count


                'extract the TextBox values

                Dim box1 As TextBox = DirectCast(Gridview1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(1).FindControl("txtname"), TextBox)

                Dim box2 As TextBox = DirectCast(Gridview1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(2).FindControl("txtaddress"), TextBox)

                Dim box3 As TextBox = DirectCast(Gridview1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(3).FindControl("txtemail"), TextBox)


                lblPreviewName.Text = box1.Text
                lblPrevieweAddress.Text = box2.Text
                lblPreviewEmail.Text = box3.Text
                'get the values from the TextBoxes

                'then add it to the collections with a comma "," as the delimited values

                sc.Add(lblPreviewName.Text + "," + lblPreviewAddress.Text + "," + lblPreviewEmail.Text)

                rowIndex += 1
            Next

            'Call the method for executing inserts

        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: how are you getting the datatable from viewstate in a different page?

Comment: also you are replacing the value in lblPreviewName.Text so only the last value will be visible after execution. I believe the variable Sc should have all the values you put.